# For WM_GETMINMAXINFO, if I'm not modifying ptMax­Size, do I still need to use MonitorFromWindow() to fix up unusual situations?

Tags: winapi

I'm probably misunderstanding something but:

I don't want the user to be able to resize my window smaller than the minimum size that its children can be visible in with a given layout. So I could do this with `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, modifying `ptMinTrackSize`.

Now, [these](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/01/10611357.aspx) [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/04/10611928.aspx) talk about compensating for multiple monitors on the `ptMax­Size` field of the `MINMAXINFO` structure, in the case where the desired window size doesn't fit on one dimension of the monitor but does on the other, using `MonitorFromWindow()`.

My confusion is: do I need to do this adjustment *always*, or only if I actually put something custom in `ptMax­Size`? If the latter, then I will assume either `DefWindowProc()` or the window manager handles it for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You already like what DefWindowProc() does, just modify ptMinTrackSize afterwards.

Comment: Right, that completely skipped my mind this time for some reason. Thanks.